# unreachable code detected in a foreach

Tags: c#, sharepoint, code-analysis, fxcop

I have got this warning in vs2012 but can't figure out *where is the unreachable code.*

```
private void LoadGridData()
{
    string currentUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;

    var jobInfoList = new List<JobInfo>();

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
        {
            using (var clientSiteCollection = new SPSite(currentUrl))
            {
                foreach (
                    SPWeb web in
                        clientSiteCollection.AllWebs.Where(
                            c =>
                            c.AllProperties[Constants.WebProperties.General.WebTemplate] != null &&
                            c.AllProperties[Constants.WebProperties.General.WebTemplate].ToString() ==
                            Constants.WebTemplates.JobWebPropertyName).OrderByDescending(d => d.Created).Take(5)
                    )
                {
                    SPList jobInfoListSp = web.Lists.TryGetList(Constants.Lists.JobInfoName);
                    if (jobInfoListSp != null)
                    {
                        if (jobInfoListSp.Items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            var value =
                                new SPFieldUrlValue(
                                    jobInfoListSp.Items[0][Constants.FieldNames.Job.Link].ToString());

                            jobInfoList.Add(new JobInfo
                                {
                                    JobName =
                                        jobInfoListSp.Items[0][Constants.FieldNames.Job.JobName].ToString(),
                                    JobCode =
                                        jobInfoListSp.Items[0][Constants.FieldNames.Job.JobCode].ToString(),
                                   Link = value.Url,
                                    JobWebsite = web.Url,
                                    IsConfidential =
                                        Convert.ToBoolean(
                                            jobInfoListSp.Items[0][Constants.FieldNames.Job.Confidential])
                                });
                        }
                    }

                    web.Dispose();
                }
            }
        });

    _lastCreatedJobsGrid.DataSource = jobInfoList;
    _lastCreatedJobsGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: do you have any code above this code which would never let this code execute?

Comment: or any code inside the actual loop?

Comment: Which line is unreachable? Can you come up with a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: according to VS, the unreachable LINE is the foreach itself, thats why its strange for me. I updated the code to include all method.

Comment: shame on the downvoters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stupid answer lol , one of the constants was moved of place, then the class was not compiling anymore, however the warning was there, Once I fixed the constant reference then the warning is gone.